# How to determine whether there exists a string pair of cyclic rotation?

Tags: string, sorting, radix-sort

I came across an interview problem online:

**Cyclic rotations.** Two strings *s* and *t* are cyclic rotations of one another if they have the same length and *s* consists of a suffix of *t* followed by a prefix of *t*. For example, "suffixsort" and "sortsuffix" are cyclic rotations.

Given *n* distinct strings, each of length *L*, design an algorithm to determine whether there exists a pair of distinct strings that are cyclic rotations of one another. For example, the following list of *n* = 12 of length *L* = 10 contains exactly one pair of strings ("suffixsort" and "sortsuffix") that are cyclic rotations of one another.

algorithms, polynomial, sortsuffix, boyermoore,

structures, minimumcut, suffixsort, stackstack,

binaryheap, digraphdfs, stringsort, digraphbfs.

The order of growth of the running time should be *nL^2*
(or better) in the worst case. Assume that the alphabet size *R* is a small constant.

**Hint:** define a fingerprint of a string in such a way that two strings are cyclic rotations of one another if and only if they have the same fingerprint.

How to solve this problem? I can't come up with useful fingerprint in the hint, but if I just check every pairs it will cost *n^2L* time.

Comment: I've done a web search for this, and I haven't found a "fingerprint" based algorithm. The simplest check is create a string that is a concatenation of one of the strings (two copies of the string one after the other), then do a search for the other string in the concatenated string, perhaps using memchr() to find the first matching character.

Comment: Regarding the fingerprint and radix sort, radix sort typically creates a histogram. Assuming that the strings contain only the 26 lower case letters, then a histogram is an array 26 counts of occurrences of each letter, without regard to the order. These arrays of counts  along with some type of string identifier could then be sorted and then scanned in order to find equal arrays of counts. If a pair of equal arrays of counts is found then the corresponding strings could be checked to see if they cyclic rotations of each other.